# WPF+MVVM, как организовать архитектуру окна?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Упрощу реальную задачу для примера - есть вьюшка окна, в окне есть несколько кнопок и условная панель. По нажатию на каждую кнопку в панели должна появляться форма с текстбоксами, лейблами, комбобоксами, etc, причем у каждой кнопки своя форма. 
Вопрос в том, как правильно организовать архитектуру всего окна с учетом паттерна MVVM и того, что кнопочки могут/будут со временем добавляться, а вместе с ними, соответственно, и формы.
Самым тупым вариантом будет каждую формочку вынести в отдельный UserControl, добавить их скопом в главное окно и просто скрывать/показывать, но этот вариант видится мне не самым оптимальным. Возможно есть более лаконичные варианты?

Comment: Непонятно зачем вы хотите использовать UserControl'ы если у вас отдельные формы - это попытка все оставить на одном экране без появления модальных окон?

Comment: Под «формой» вы имеете в виду просто прямоугольный элемент с контролами внутри? Вам стоит тогда представить ваш список форм как `ItemsControl`, а саму форму — как `ItemTemplate`. Добавление формы сведётся к добавлению элемента в `ObservableCollection`, которая выступает как `ItemsSource` для вашего `ItemsControl`'а.